# How to gracefully stop Python service with async tasks

Tags: python, service, python-asyncio

I have a small python service which runs several asyncio tasks in an infinite loop. Tasks are for checking states of k8s pods and saving some calculations into db.

My goal is to make graceful stop/restart of service. It means in case of terminating the service I want all running tasks to be finished.

I wrote this code, but as for me it seems quite ugly. Especially the use of globals and two while loops in main function.

Are there any ways to reach my goal with more efficient and simple code?

**Python 3.10**

```
import asyncio
import signal
    
running = True
tasks = set()
    
async def sometask():
    global running
    while running:
        print('Some work on internet')
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        print('Some work part 2')

def shutdown():
    global running
    print('shutdown')
    running = False

async def main():      
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()    
    loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGINT, shutdown)
    
    task: asyncio.Task = asyncio.create_task(sometask())
    task.add_done_callback(tasks.discard)
    tasks.add(task)
    
    while running:
        print(f'Running: {running}...{len(tasks)}')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        
    while len(tasks) > 0:
        print(f'Waiting for {len(tasks)} tasks to finish')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        
    print('Finish')
    

asyncio.run(main(), debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [task cancellation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#task-cancellation) to propagate the stop signal. Here is an example:

```py
import asyncio


async def long_running():
    print("Task started")
    try:
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print("Some graceful shutdown logic here")
    print("Task ended")


async def main():
    t = asyncio.create_task(long_running())

    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    t.cancel()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

In your case, trigger `task.cancel` when a stop signal is received.